# Grabbing an HTML value with JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, javabeans

I have a javascript that edits a hidden field in my jsf page:

```
<h:inputHidden id="data"  value="" />
```

and when I click on "Submit" I would like to get the new value of this HTML field that was modified by the javascript.  I've looked into

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("data");
```

But that seems only to work if it is passed in as an `<f:param/>`.  Is there a way i can get the value through a bean call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the generated HTML input field which get sent as request parameter the usual HTTP/HTML way. Remember: JSF runs at webserver, produces HTML/CSS/JS, webserver sends it by HTTP to webbrowser, webbrowser retrieves HTML/CSS/JS and displays/applies/executes it. Rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source*, locate the generated HTML input element and you'll see something similar this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="formid:data" name="formid:data" />
```

where `formid` is the ID of the parent `<form>` as generated by JSF `<h:form>`. As per the HTML spec, input values get sent as name=value pairs in request parameters.

So, for the above case, you should be using

```
data = requestParameterMap.get("formid:data");
```

---

However, you can also just bind it to a bean property.

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.data}" />
```

This way it'll just be available as `data` property in the bean's action method without the need to hassle with request parameters the low-level way.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, I put in the formId:data the first time and it didn't work.  but now it does!!  Thank you very much BalucC your posts and blog have really helped me significantly in jsf development :)

Comment: binding is a better option it's valid for any bean scope!